# Do Doxygen config files support variables?

Tags: doxygen

For instance I set the source code path as c:\code\testapp\src. Is this then available as a var I can use - for instance so I can spit out a tag file in a location relative to this, not relative to the working dir of doxygen? I think I'm looking for something like how Ant defines vars for just about everything and these can be re-used; does Doxygen have special vars for any of the config values?

I'm thinking like $PROJECT-NAME or %VERSION% or whatever...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use environment variables in the configuration file; the syntax is the same as in a makefile, i.e. `$(VAR_NAME)`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but I have seen people use variables as part of their build process.  For example the lemon graph library uses cmake, sets a variable for the absolute file path in cmake and the doxygen config file includes variables such as `@abs_top_srcdir@`.  Through the build process these variables are replaced with the relevant text.

Comment: Here's a blog post about what you mentioned http://majewsky.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/tip-of-the-day-cmake-and-doxygen/

Comment: Getting the zombies out, this is not valid. It bases on CMake mechanism, which allows you to replace ANY file var. Although a useful tip, if you ask me.